# Quais as diferenças entre propriedades e atributos no HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, característica-linguagem

Ao tentar utilizar este código:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectAllBoxes").on("click", function(){
       if(this.checked){
           $('.checkBoxes').each(function(){
               $(this).attr("checked", true);
           });
       } else {
           $('.checkBoxes').each(function(){
               $(this).attr("checked", false); 
           });
       }
}
```

Percebi que não é mais possível acessar no jQuery o "checked" com o método attr, apenas com prop.
Após algumas pesquisas encontrei que as propriedades do HTML são elementos que podemos definir como booleanos enquanto os atributos podem ser adicionados ao HTML e não são booleanos, porém achei esta explicação bastante generalizada.
Gostaria de saber o que são as propriedades e atributos e quais as suas diferenças.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para perceber a diferença é preciso ter em conta que HTML e JavaScript são linguagens diferentes.

Assim:

- o HTML tem elementos com atributos
- o JavaScript tem objetos com propriedades

O DOM é a interceção entre JavaScript e HTML, algo que não há por exemplo em Node.js. Assim os objetos do DOM ao qual o JavaScript têm acesso têm propriedades que são a representação dos atributos de HTML.

Os objetos que não tenham a propriedade de um dado atributo definida o JavaScript usa o valor do atributo.

Exemplos:

```js
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
var c = document.getElementById('c');

console.log(a.checked, a.disabled); // true false
console.log(b.checked, b.disabled); // false true

c.setAttribute('disabled', true);
c.checked = true;
console.log(c.checked, c.disabled); // true true
```

```html
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="a"/>
<input disabled type="checkbox" id="b"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="c"/>
```

O exemplo `a` e `b` comportam-se como esperado, o JavaScript lê as propriedades importando o valor dos atributos do elemento HTML.

O exemplo `c` não tem nada definido no HTML mas nós atribuímos valor a `checked` e `disabled` mudando a propriedade do objeto, resp. atributo do HTML.

Outro exemplo:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');

c.checked = false;

console.log(c.checked, c.getAttribute('checked')); // false true
```

```html
<input checked="true" type="checkbox" id="c" />
```

Neste exemplo em cima a diferença fica ainda mais clara, o `.checked` (propriedade do objeto) muda o valor só no JavaScript e não no HTML onde o atributo permanece com o valor inicial.

Comment: Excelente explicação, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Velasco de nada, boa pergunta!