# Alterar `id` de elemento <Form> javascript ou jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso alterar o **id** de um formulário em **HTML** com javascript em tempo de execução.

Estou tentando com JQuery e Javascript, mas não está funcionando.

```
jQuery(this).prev("form").attr("form", "form_modulo");
```

ou

```
document.getElementById('form').id = 'form_form_modulo';
```

Nenhum dos dois funciona, quando vou ver o código da pagina ainda está o valor antigo

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss , foi na hora de digitar aqui errei na escrita, já atualizei na pergunta. Obg

Comment: Qual é a necessidade de alterar o valor do `id` de um elemento? E não adianta olhar o código fonte da página. Este não muda. Precisa olhar o DOM nas ferramentas de desenvolvimento do navegador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para alterar o ID podes mudar a propriedade do objeto DOM ou o atributo do elemento HTML. São coisas diferentes, [expliquei mais sobre isso aqui nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/208023/129).

Mudar propriedade:
<sub>(Referiste esta maneira na resposta, e está correta. É uma das maneiras)</sub>

```
// JavaScript nativo
document.getElementById('form').id = 'form_form_modulo';
// jQuery:
$('#form').prop('id', 'form_form_modulo');
```

Mudar atributo:

```
// JavaScript nativo
document.getElementById('form').setAttribute('id', 'form_form_modulo');
// jQuery:
$('#form').attr('id', 'form_form_modulo'):
```

Ambos fazem o que queres, mas mudando só a propriedade isso não vai ser visível no HTML quando inspecionas com as ferramentas dev.

[Li nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219160/alterar-id-de-elemento-form-javascript-ou-jquery#comment449683_219165) que tentaste

```js
function SalvarBotoes() {
  alert($('#form').attr('id'));
  $('#form').attr('id', 'form_modulo');
  alert($('#form').attr('id'));
  form.submit();
}
```

A razão disso dar undefined é porque a ultima chamada a `$('#form')` já não vai dar nada exatamente porque mudaste o ID e esse seletor já não encontra nenhum elemento com esse ID. Terias de ter:

```js
function SalvarBotoes() {
  var $form = $('#form');
  alert($form.attr('id'));
  $form.attr('id', 'form_modulo');
  alert($form.attr('id'));
  $form[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: obrigado era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode tentar algo como:

```
$('#meu_form').attr('id','novo_id');
```

Comment: tentei fazer $('#form').attr('id','novo_id'); O nome do meu formulario é `form`

Comment: E mesmo assim não funciona @InteliderSistemas?

Comment: @FabianoLothor funcionou obigado, estava errando na logica

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#texto', function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
  $(this).attr('id', 'NewID');
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="texto">TEXTO</button>
```

Segue o exemplo

Comment: vi o exemplo funcionando ok, porém, pela minha falta de entrosamento com Jquery, javascript não to conseguindo adequar ao que eu preciso, to tentando fazer assim `function SalvarBotoes() {
    alert($('#form').attr('id'));
    $('#form').attr('id', 'form_modulo');
    alert($('#form').attr('id'));
    form.submit();
}`, porém no ultimo alert onde deveria alterar o nome do formulario envia retorna somente `Undefined`. Se coloco o `$('#form').attr('form', 'form_modulo');` , ele não altera o id.