# Atribuindo valor a um input - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Eu tenho dois `input type="hidden"` do qual faço uma requisição Ajax para um arquivo externo para poder atribuir valores ao mesmo. A requisição está me retornando o valor corretamente, tudo está certo nela, porém esses valores não estão sendo atribuídos aos `input`, pois eles ficam com os valores do qual é colocado no próprio `HTML` mesmo e eu não sei o porque isso está acontecendo.

**Código dos input:**

```
<input type="text" name="cartao_adicionado" id="cartao_adicionado" value="0" />
<input type="text" name="cartao_adicionado_product_id" id="cartao_adicionado_product_id"" value="0" />
```

**Código da requisição Ajax:**

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
        $j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "verifica.php",
            data:{

            },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(retorno){
                $j('#cartao_adicionado').val(retorno['adicionado']);
                $j('#cartao_adicionado_product_id').val(retorno['id_produto']);
            },
            complete: function(){

            },
            error: function(x,y,z){
                alert(x);
                alert(y);
                alert(z);
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: O que dá `console.log(typeof retorno, retorno);`?

Comment: @Sergio Isso me retorna os valores corretos do quais dou o retorno no meu arquivo externo.

Comment: Matheus, coloca aqui o resultado pf.

Comment: @Sergio `Object {adicionado: "1", id_produto: "13"}`

Comment: Obrigado. Há mais elementos com esse ID `#cartao_adicionado` ou somente 1 na página?

Comment: @Sergio Somente um na página.

Comment: Os inputs a que te referes, que queres escrever no success, são `type="text"` ou `type="hidden"`?

Comment: @Sergio No sucess, quero `type="hidden"`, mas deixo como `type=text` para saber qual é o valor que está sendo atribuído ao mesmo.

Comment: Se fizeres diretamente na consola `$j('#cartao_adicionado').val('so-um-teste');` o valor muda?

Comment: @Sergio O valor exibido muda, porém inspecionando o elemento, o valor continua 0.

Comment: E quando usas como tens na pergunta o valor também muda mas o inspecionado não muda é isso?

Comment: @Sergio Seria isso mesmo.

Comment: Nesse caso acho que estás a misturar conceitos. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/208023/129

Comment: Ou seja, o valor mudou como queres mas o atributo do HTML não muda pois é o `value` que lhe deste no inicio. É mesmo assim e quando fizeres de novo `$j('#cartao_adicionado').val();` depois do ajax vais ver que o valor é o que queres.

Comment: @Sergio Então, como eu poderia corrigir essa questão?

Comment: Refereste à pergunta aqui ou ao código no teu projeto?

Comment: No teu projeto está tudo certo. O valor do ajax está a ser colocado no input.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65562/discussion-between-sergio-and-matheus-portela).

Comment: @Sergio Tudo bem.